# Change SQL into Query Builder in Laravel

Tags: php, sql

This is my SQL statement

```
SELECT `pams_users`.display_name,`pams_user_levels`.description FROM pams_users 
JOIN pams_developer ON `pams_users`.developer_id=`pams_developer`.id AND `pams_developer`.id=27 OR `pams_users`.`parent_dev`=27
JOIN pams_user_levels ON `pams_user_levels`.id=`pams_users`.user_level AND `pams_user_levels`.id=6
GROUP BY  `pams_users`.display_name
```

This is my query builder based on the SQL

```
 DB::table('pams_users')
        ->join('pams_developer','pams_developer.id','pams_users.developer_id')
        ->join('pams_user_levels','pams_user_levels.id','pams_users.user_level')
        ->where('pams_developer.id',27)
        ->orWhere('pams_users.parent_dev',27)
        ->where('pams_user_levels.id',6)
        ->select('developer_name','description','display_name')
        ->selectRaw('count(pams_users.id) as count')
        ->groupBy('display_name')
        ->get();
```

However, the query builder did not show any error but show different result with the SQL statement.
Anyone can figure out my query builder problem ?
Any suggestion and comment on my query builder is appreciated.

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is probably the OR WHERE clause not being encapsulated by the Eloquent query builder there. You can pass a closure into `where()` for it to do that, as shown below.

I've also grouped the selects into a single method call, with using `DB::raw` instead of the `selectRaw()` method.

```
DB::table('pams_users')
    ->join('pams_developer','pams_developer.id','pams_users.developer_id')
    ->join('pams_user_levels','pams_user_levels.id','pams_users.user_level')
    ->select([
        'developer_name',
        'description',
        'display_name',
        DB::raw('count(pams_users.id) as count'), // this avoids the separate selectRaw()
    ])
    ->where(function($query) {
        $query->where('pams_developer.id',27)
            ->orWhere('pams_users.parent_dev',27);
    })
    ->where('pams_user_levels.id',6)
    ->groupBy('display_name')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Ohhh, I am sorry, I just saw your reply now. However, I solved it already. Thanks you !!